# "Authentication credentials were not provided." and terminal says Unauthorized: /api/auth/login/ django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am using postman. when i do a post request to api/auth/login/, I get a 401 response "Authentication credentials were not provided.". In terminal, I do not get my print statement inside of the login serializer, I get Unauthorized: /api/auth/login/. This is my code:
settings.py

```
#just including the rest framework one here
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': 
       (
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',)
}
```

views.py

```
#just everything user related
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')

class LoginUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        print(user)
        if user:# and user.is_active:
            return user
        print("failed")
        raise serializers.ValidationError("No no to log in with provided credentials.")
#Views
class RegistrationAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })

class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        })
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/games', GameViewset, 'games-name')

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^", include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^api/auth/', include('knox.urls')),
    re_path(r"^api/auth/register/$", RegistrationAPI.as_view()),
    re_path(r"^api/auth/login/$", LoginAPI.as_view())
]
```

Comment: must be permission related issue, seems like your tried logged in user is not admin as in your setting you define `IsAdminUser` as default permission_class.

Comment: @Shakil I also tried a number of other settings combos and nothing worked. Such as having knox in as the only authentication class, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please add these two lines at LoginAPI.

```
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    # This 2 lines
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer
```

As you can see at settings `'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES'('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',)`

That is why you have to override in view to avoid to be authenticated.